# Issue mocking SpEL expression functions in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-test-mvc

In my RestController called ProductController I have defined a few PreAuthorize functions, example:

```
@PreAuthorize("@userIsOwnerOfEntity.apply(#id, principal.claims['user_id'])")
```

This function checks if the userId is the actual owner of the product before they can save/update the entity. This is the implementation in another file called ProductControllerSecurity.class which is annotated as a Service.

```
@Autowired
public GetProductImpl getProductImpl;

@Bean
public BiFunction<ProductDto, String, Boolean> userIsOwnerOfEntity() {
    return (product, userId) -> {
       Product check = getProductImpl.execute(product.getProductId());
       return check.getUserId().toString().equals(userId);
    };
}
```

Now I would like to mock the userIsOwnerOfEntity functionality in my ProductControllerTest.class but I hit a wall.

In my test I have the following mocking implementation:

```
@Autowired public BiFunction<ProductDto, String, Boolean> userIsOwnerOfEntity;
when(userIsOwnerOfEntity.apply(any(ProductDto.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

The test imports a file called ProductControllerSecurityTest.class which has the following Bean:

```
@MockBean(name="userIsOwnerOfEntity") public BiFunction<ProductDto, String, Boolean> userIsOwnerOfEntity;
```

So I assume that the mocked SpEL function should just return **true**. But I'm getting the following error;

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Boolean.booleanValue()" because the return value of "org.springframework.expression.Expression.getValue(org.springframework.expression.EvaluationContext, java.lang.Class)" is null

Which I believe tells me that the SpEL function is not returning **true**.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So instead of using @WebMvcTest I needed to use @SpringBootTest together with @AutoConfigureMockMvc. Then it correctly mocked the SpEL expression correctly.

```
when(userIsOwnerOfEntity.apply(any(ProductDto.class), anyString())).thenReturn(true);
```

The code above now behaves as expected.

This solved the following errors:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1058E: A problem occurred when trying to resolve bean 'Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory'

Caused by: org.springframework.expression.AccessException: Could not resolve bean reference against BeanFactory

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userIsOwnerOfEntity' available
```